# How to catch window close in Safari extension before it is closed?

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

In Chrome extensions there is a way to detect window close event before it is closed:

```
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function (tabId, removeInfo) {
    if ( removeInfo.isWindowClosing ) ...
});
```

`isWindowClosing` is true only if the whole window is closing, not if you close the last tab in the window (which also ends up in closing the window).

I'm wandering, is there a way to acheive same thing in Safari extensions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "close" event or beforeNavigate event to do what you need.

IF that doesn't work, you can always inject a content script into your page and listen to the "beforeunload" event. When that event is fired (which is before the page is unloaded) you can send a message to your global context using the messaging API.